# I need the "if" to go once but not end the loop

Tags: python, keyboard, mouse

I'm making a program to control the mouse with WASD but whenever I press the button the mouse just moves to the top of the screen when I need it to move slightly then be able to move again if I press the key again

I've tried to have the loop turn off then back on but it just ends the loop before it can switch back on.

```
import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Controller
mouse = Controller()
repeat = True
while repeat:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
        mouse.move(0, -5)

    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        mouse.move(0, 5)
```

I need it to move up slightly when I press w but stop when it isn't pressed so I can press it again.

Answer (score 0):

You might want your keyboard not to be so sensitive, so you may need to sample the pressing time. `sleep` can help in this case. In the code below, the program will sleep for `0.2` seconds every time it enters `while` loop.

```py
import keyboard
import time

repeat = True
while repeat:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
        mouse.move(0, -5)

    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        mouse.move(0, 5)

    # do something
```

---

EDIT: I was misunderstanding what you want, just `sleep` is enough for this. The problem is because your computer does everything too fast, so a while loop might be completed in a microsecond or less. So it sees that you are pressing the key for too long (though you think you did fast) then it just repeats the loop until you release the key. That's why your mouse always moves to the top.

Sampling is the way to tell computer "if you've done, then sleep, don't do anything else".

Another way is to count how many times it loops (ie, scaling), but it looks like dump since the computer has to do worthless things.

```py
import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Controller
mouse = Controller()
repeat = True
w_count, s_count = 0, 0
while repeat:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
        w_count += 1
        if w_count == 10:              # i'm scaling it
            mouse.move(0, -5)
            w_count = 0

    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        s_count += 1
        if s_count == 10:              # i'm scaling it
            mouse.move(0, 5)
            s_count = 0
```

There are also other ways: measure the pressing time, edge detection (detect key release)... You can search about "software debouncing" for more ideas and find one best fits your requirement.

Comment: thanks, I didn't think of that as I thought the problem was the loop not stopping